# Is $\mathbb{R}^2-B$ path connected where $B = \{(x,y) : x^2+y^2=1 \} \cup \{(x,y) : (x-2)^2 +y^2 \le1 \}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

$B = \{(x,y) : x^2+y^2=1 \} \cup \{(x,y) : (x-2)^2 +y^2 \le1 \}$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because $(0,1)$ is a limit point in both sets.

I am not sure how to continue beyond this to prove/disprove $\mathbb{R}^2-B$ is path connected

Comment: This is false. The open unit disk a bounded component and there is an unbounded component too.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). See my edit.